# How can I cache dependencies for deployment using chef?

Tags: deployment, chef-infra

Lately I ran into an issue when deploying some chef-based recipies in a vagrant environment. One of the components I tried to install (percona xtradbcluster) was temporary unavailable (the percona ubuntu repo contained a faulty build). Although the guys over at Percona's fixed the issue during the weekend, I couldn't deploy my test setup for a while, without really having an alternative to fix it.

This got me thinking: at deploy time, I depend on a whole slew of "things" being available over the Internet: ubuntu repos 3rd party repos, packages being available within those repos, ruby gems being available, etc, etc... Any of these might (temporary) be unavailable, making it impossible to deploy.

My question: is it possible to cache all my dependancies? Is it worth it, or should I just live with the occasional glitch? How do you deal with this?

Thanks!
Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Opscode's "apt" cookbook to set up an apt cache on one of your systems, then the other systems can use it for their apt sources.

On the system that is to be the cache, put `recipe[apt::cacher-ng]` in its run list (or use a role).

On all other systems, put `recipe[apt::cacher-client]` in the run list (e.g., in a "base" role applied to all systems). If you're using Chef Solo, you'll need to set the attribute `node['apt']['cacher_ipaddress']` to the IP of the cache system.

Then all packages installed will be cached, and other systems will install from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Chef actually does some caching for you, but only for **remote_file** resource. But when it concerns package installation, then Chef totally relies on package provider, meaning that it runs the shell commands calling `apt-get install` (or yum or smth. else) and apt can cache some downloaded packages, but it does not depend on chef in any way.

And I am not aware of anything that can help with predowloading some remote content. The only thing we did in our company is that we created some local file storage for bigger files (>500Mb) and for files that we are pretty sure will be needed on several machines. (for example we have java containers installed everywhere) Then we provide links to local store in our recipes and new machine will download it from there.

The only thing that comes to mind how this can be improved is that:

You create your own LWRPs based on **remote_file** or **package** resources. And when they receive some url to download from or package name, they somehow try to download it from local repository first, and only if they fail then they try to do it using remote url. But there might be problems matching remote url and local repository url.